# can't install eclipse 3.6 in ubuntu 10.04

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, repository

I can't install eclipse 3.6 in ubuntu 10.04

Synaptic gives me version 3.5.2 but the current version is 3.6.1
I tried `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:eclipse-team/debian-package` but still nothing.

Is there another repository, or should i download and install manually?

EDIT: I chose to work with the 3.5.2 version.

Comment: Just download the file and run it.

Comment: Did you set the executable permission to the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version included in Ubuntu is usually a bit behind the official release, due to the way that Ubuntu updating works and they focus on robustness instead of newness.

If you want the very latest version, you must download it yourself, unpack it and run the `eclipse` binary.

Comment: athspk@quad:~/Downloads/eclipse$ ./eclipse   
bash: ./eclipse: cannot execute binary file  .There is something i am doing wrong